# Adding HTML code into div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div:

```
<div id="bottom">
</div>
```

And now I would like to create table there, where will be placed things from Js array.
I tried this:

```
document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML("Text");
```

But it doesn't work :/

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'innerHTML' of object # is not a function

Answer (score 3):

`innerHTML` is a property and no method. Use it like this:

```
document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = "Text";
```

More [information at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't need any methods as innerHTML is a property and u can use it as below

```
document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = "Text";
```

happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You have this error becouse of `innerHTML` should be assigned to `htmlString`. Something like this:

```
document.getElementById('bottom').innerHTML = '<table><tr><td>Text</td></tr></table>';
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter what you pass in as long as you use it like a property and not like a function call.

Comment: Yes, it's like ordinary property of object